# Stop Bazaar (bzr) from making .moved files

Tags: bazaar, version-control

Is there a way to tell `bzr` not to create `.moved` files? I've tried the `--overwrite` option with a `bzr pull`, but it still creates the .moved files. I guess I can just make a clean-up script, but I was just wondering if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicts in some filenames: either you have unversioned foo in your tree and you pull revision where foo becomes versioned, or you have added foo in two different branches independently and therefore each copy of foo got assigned different file-ids. So Bazaar tries to save your files there and avoid overwrite your existing files. In the first case you have harmless backup facility from bzr, and foo.moved can be deleted. But in the second case you have real conflict and you should at least inspect both foo and foo.moved and resolve conflict with `bzr resolve foo`, then delete foo.moved if needed.

So the strategy to avoid .moved files is pretty much depend on the reason why they are appear in your tree.

Comment: The contents of the files involved are identical.

Comment: @Kristopher Ives: Content does not matter here, because you have no text conflict, but instead filenames conflict. Bazaar track the files using internal unique identifiers. So you either have different file-ids problem or trying to get the changes to the tree where foo unversioned, but in the revision you're pulling it's still versioned. You can file a bug though.